# evit duplicity in pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've created a T-SQL code to receive some data like this:

[image: img1]

But this cause duplicity of CODART and NOMBRE when the data is in different columns(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL5,....)

and I would like to appear all the data in ONE row, something like this:

[image: img2]

this is my code:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT sum(CUENTA) [cuenta], CODIGO,(select max(ar.nombre) from 
CON.dbo.ARTICULOS ar where ar.codart=a.Codigo) as NOMBRE,
  COL from LIBRO_COLUMNA l group by COL,CODIGO,
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(cuenta) FOR COL IN('+@columns+')
) AS pivottable ORDER BY CODIGO;';
--PRINT @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

The estructure and some data of the table:

```
COL        codigo           nombre                     Cuenta

*--------------------------------------------------------------------

COL5     |  PHOBA802   |    TAPA FINAL D-UT 2,5/10   |  3624.00

COL 5    |  PHOBA8021  |    TAPA FINAL D-UT 16       |  159.00

COL 5    |  PHOBA803   |    TAPA FINAL D-UT 2,5/4    |  1950.00

COL 10   |  PHOBA803   |                             |  447.00

COL 1    |  PHOBA803   |    TAPA UT 2,5-4            |  138.00
```

The problem here is that if want a pivot with COL I need to group by CODIGO and COL,and I don´t know two to do it without grouping by COL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can u show what is your input and output data

Comment: @Chanukya What you need to show?, i don´t have very clear what you refer with Input and Output, i put the output in the first photo and the input is the table, i put it an the end of the post.
Sorry i don´t understand very well, perhaps you are asking me for another thing, if this, please say me

Comment: i need proper input tables which u joined in dynamic query .. @Ion

Comment: @Chanukya Sorry, I supose yo refer to the @@columns variable in the pivot?
This is a simplification of the code, for simplicity the contain of@@ columns is
[COL1],[COL2],[COL3],[COL4],[COL5],[COL6],[COL7],[COL8],[COL9],[COL10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'
SELECT
    subquery.*
    , (select max(ar.nombre) from 
CON.dbo.ARTICULOS ar where ar.codart=subquery.Codigo) as NOMBRE
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT sum(CUENTA) [cuenta],
  COL from LIBRO_COLUMNA l group by COL,CODIGO
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(cuenta) FOR COL IN('+@columns+')
) AS pivottable

) subquery ORDER BY subquery.CODIGO;
';
--PRINT @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

---- Added later----

More explanation on the why.

In the text T-SQL Fundamental and the one prepare for 70-461 exam, Itzik Ben-Gan explained the PIVOT.

```
SELECT <select list>
FROM (
    SELECT
        <grouping column>
        , <spreading column>
        , <aggregating column>
    ) PIVOT ( <aggregate function> (<aggregation column>)
        FOR <spreading column> IN (<spreading values>) ) as P;
```

From my understanding of his writing, by added in the (select max...) row, you added in a grouping column in there
(think of the grouping as part of the ... GROUP BY grouping column, spreading column).

In this situation, I moved the (select max...) row out of the table being pivoted and hence remove the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry for not responding(i was in my eat time), this looks great, the only thing is i have a some problems with one  close parenthesis.
And where you put ', (select max(ar.nombre) from 
CON.dbo.ARTICULOS ar where ar.codart=a.Codigo) as NOMBRE', ¿perhaps it will be ar.codart=subquery.codigo? because is a column name from the subquery

Comment: Yes. I fixed it there.

Comment: Well, this works perfect(you need to delete de last comma in in the 11 row from the end),. Only for my curiosity/knowledge how do this to solve the problema of the duplicity??, because what i see is that the obtain all the data from the subquery without doing any more??

Comment: I added the explanation.